# If you have a reference type field in a document in firestore, can you cache the reference's data without extra reads?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of news and each news contains references to its channel. My question is if I cache the news data will I be able to get the data of the channel as well without a huge number of reads?

Answer (score 0):

> If I cache the news data will I be able to get the data of the channel as well without a huge number of reads?

No. If a document contains a reference to another document, it doesn't mean that the document at which the reference is pointing will also be in cache. That reference is just a path to a document and **not** actual document.